# Unable to create SQL database in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, command-line-interface, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I am trying to create a sql database using cloud shell

**Note:** I am able to create the sql database in the same resource group without any issues.

When i execute the command from the the cloud shell I get the following error message.

```
PS /home/xxx> az sql db create -g akshandsonlab -s aksdatabase -n mhcdb --service-objective S0
ResourceNotFoundError: The Resource 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/aksdatabase' under resource group 'akshandsonlab' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
```

I have followed the above link but I am reaching a dead end.

Can any one shed some light on this

Regards

Sudlo

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you have selected the correct subscription when you create the SQL database via `az account show`.

If not, you could list the subscription(`az account list`) then set the subscription(`az account set -s <subscriptionID>`) that you want to create the resource.

If not, you could double-check the Resource name and Resource group name.

For more information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-not-found

Comment: Could you run `az account clear` then `az login`, then you can run `az account list` to check it? Or any typo? Have you tried to run it from a local shell instead of a cloud shell?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I am able to create the sql database in the same resource group
> without any issues.

It looks like you want to create your database in a different resource group than that of your SQL server, which is not possible [as of today](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/13207131-allow-sql-databases-to-exist-in-a-resource-group-d). The SQL server and DB must exist in the [same resource group](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b33fa02e-b918-49a5-ad66-55d3f1fafedd/sql-database-and-sql-server-resource-groups?forum=ssdsgetstarted).

This is most likely the reason you're seeing this error. Instead, run the command passing the resource group where your SQL server exists.

```
az sql db create -g <sql-server-resource-group> -s aksdatabase -n mhcdb --service-objective S0
```